# Python 2.7 Why I only write one line of a list to file instead of the whole list

Tags: python, list, parsing, for-loop, beautifulsoup

Originally, my code is:

```
# encoding = utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import os

url = []
urlbase = "https://quizlet.com/subject/四级乱序/page/"
for i in range(0,2):
    url.append(urlbase + str(i+1))
    indexname = str(url[i])[-1] + ".html"
    urllib.urlretrieve(url[i], indexname)
    print indexname + " downloaded"
    f = open(indexname,"r")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
    linkclass = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"SetPreview-link","href":re.compile(r"unit(\s\w+)?")})
    for link in link class:
        flink = link.get("href")
        print flink
```

The result is a number of links, works just fine.

**BUT when I write it to a file in code like this:**

```
# encoding = utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import os
url = []
urlbase = "https://quizlet.com/subject/四级乱序/page/"
flinkfile = open("links.txt",'wb')
for i in range(0,2):
    url.append(urlbase + str(i+1))
    indexname = str(url[i])[-1] + ".html" 
    urllib.urlretrieve(url[i], indexname)
    print indexname + " downloaded"
    f = open(indexname,"r")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
    linkclass = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"SetPreview-link", "href":re.compile(r"unit(\s\w+)?")})
    for link in linkclass:
        flink = link.get("href")
        flinkfile.writelines(flink)
    flinkfile.close()
```

The result is a txt file with only one line like this:
https://quizlet.com/146113318/unit31-flash-cards/

Why is that?

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the file close is inside the `for i in range(0,2)` loop. If you move it out you should get more lines (assuming there are more):

```
# encoding = utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import os
url = []
urlbase = "https://quizlet.com/subject/四级乱序/page/"
flinkfile = open("links.txt",'wb')
for i in range(0,2):
    url.append(urlbase + str(i+1))
    indexname = str(url[i])[-1] + ".html" 
    urllib.urlretrieve(url[i], indexname)
    print indexname + " downloaded"
    f = open(indexname,"r")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
    linkclass = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"SetPreview-link", "href":re.compile(r"unit(\s\w+)?")})
    for link in linkclass:
        flink = link.get("href")
        flinkfile.writelines(flink)
# close file outside loop
flinkfile.close()
```

To ensure the file is closed even if an error occurs, use the `with` statement:

```
with open(...) as flinkfile:
  for in in range(0,2):
    ...
```

More info on with here: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm